# Suggestions for creating high-quality 3D line drawings

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics, 3d

When I'm creating 2D graphics for my math lectures (for Beamer presentations and lecture notes), I'm very happy with TikZ and I've been using it for many years now.  However, I still haven't found a solution for 3D graphics that I'm equally comfortable with.  I have used the 3D capabilities of TikZ as well as pgfplots.  I've also tried Asymptote and I sometimes resort to creating graphics with Mathematica and embed them in my TeX files.  You can create impressive and "realistic" 3D renderings with these tools, but that's not what I'm actually looking for.  I'd rather create monochrome *line drawings* that look like those in Hilbert's and Cohn-Vossen's wonderful book ["Anschauliche Geometrie"](https://w2.gzg-fn.de/mia/mathe/euklid/HilbertCohnVossenAnschaulicheGeometrie.pdf).  I'm attaching some examples below.

The closest I've found is [Sketch](http://sketch4latex.sourceforge.net/) and probably I should just stick with it.  But I'm asking here to check if I've been missing something.  Ideally, this would be something that can be used from within TeX without the need to run external programs (although using Lua would be fine with me).  It should offer some kind of descriptive language and should at least offer the ability to recognize hidden lines or surfaces automatically.  Any suggestions?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: If you have access to a WYSIWYG 3D graphics program, use it.  I use TikZ, pgfplots and tikz3d because it is the only graphics capability I have (other than Gimp).

Comment: You can certainly create these with asymptote, tikz or pgfplots. Only asymptote has a real 3d engine. It might be that in the beginning you are considerably slower if you use, say, asymptote but the big advantage is that, if you code things well, it is straightforward to make changes that globally affect all plots, and of course the text will match the stye of the ambient document.

Comment: @marmot Things like drawing hidden lines as dashed lines can be done with Asymptote?  I had searched for that and my impression was that that's not possible (unless you do it manually).